Python Poetry dependencies in GitHub Enterprise repositories set credentials
I am using GitHub enterprise with it GitHub actions.
In my poetry .toml file I have several dependencies to public python packages but also to other GHE repos in other organizations and their .toml file. This .toml files can have additional dependencies to other GHE repos in other organization and so on...
The installation with poetry update/install will fail due to missing credentials to the other organizations if we use Https link in .toml file.
Problem was solved with SSH link in .toml file and SSH Key for a user with access for all organisations/repos. This SSH Key was stored at the machine we run the GitHub actions runner ==> access is possible.
How can I configure or overhand credentials (personal access token) from GH actions workflow that poetry is working with all the dependencies with HTTPS link in .toml file?
With this solution we would be independent from the SSH configuration in machine..
